# Why does the n-step return being zero result in high variance in off policy n-step TD?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods, importance-sampling, return

In the paragraph given between eq 7.12 and 7.13 in [Sutton & Barto's book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=172):

> $G_{t:h} = R_{t+1} + G_{t+1:h} , t < h < T$
>
> where $G_{h:h} = V_{h-1}(S_h)$. (Recall that this return is used at time h, previously denoted t + n.) Now consider the effect of following a behavior policy $b$ that is not the same as the target policy $\pi$. All of the resulting experience, including the ﬁrst reward $R_{t+1}$ and the next state $S_{t+1}$ must be weighted by the importance sampling ratio for time $t, \rho_t = \frac{\pi(A_t|S_t)}{b(A_t|S_t)}$ . One might be tempted to simply weight the righthand side of the above equation, but one can do better. Suppose the action at time t would never be selected by $\pi$, so that $\rho_t$ is zero. Then a simple weighting would result in the n-step return being zero, which could result in high variance when it was used as a target.

Why does the n-step return being zero results in high variance?

Also, why is the experience weighted by $\rho_t$, it should be weighted by $\rho_{t:t+h}$?